# What is the correct answer?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I got 4 as the answer. I want to know whether i am correct or not.If I please explain.

Comment: How did you get 4? Does that match up with the sketch you made?

Comment: Symmetric domain, odd function.

Comment: How did you get 4 as an answer? What did you see when you sketched the function? Including a description of what you did will help others write more informative answers.

Comment: Even if you confused some stuff, that $\;4\;$ as solution seems completely unreal within this problem. What is the primitive function of $\;\sin x\;$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably been fooled by the idea that the integral represents the area between the $x$-axis and the curve, but this is correct only when the curve is in the half plane $y>0$. It is true that
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x\,dx=\Bigl[-\cos x\Bigr]_{0}^{\pi}=
-\cos\pi+\cos0=2
$$
but you need to remember that areas below the $x$-axis *count as negative*; indeed
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin x\,dx=\Bigl[-\cos x\Bigr]_{-\pi}^{\pi}=
-\cos\pi+\cos(-\pi)=0.
$$
So you can't *double the area*, but rather note that the two chunks have *opposite* areas, which cancel out.

Of course, noticing that $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$ would have spared you from the computation. If $f$ is defined and continuous (one can relax this condition to being integrable) on an interval $[-a,a]$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$, you can observe that
\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,dx
&=
\int_{-a}^0 f(x)\,dx+
\int_{0}^a f(x)\,dx\\
&=
\int_{a}^0 -f(-t)\,dt+
\int_{0}^a f(x)\,dx &&\text{(with $x=-t$ in the first integral)}\\
&=
\int_{a}^0 f(t)\,dt+
\int_{0}^a f(x)\,dx &&\text{(using $f(-t)=-f(t)$ in the first integral)}\\[8px]
&=0
\end{align}